# How do I get my Java Applet to show the card images?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet

So this is a java applet I'm not sure why it is not rendering the card (the cards filename is any number of the "types" array joined with the ".gif" extension.)
What I don't know is how to get it to render. I don't know if I did something wrong or I'm forgetting something, but if you find a problem please tell me.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Assignment12 extends JApplet {

    private final static int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;


    private static Image card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10;

    private static String[] types = {"h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","h7","h8","h9","h10","hj","hq","hk","c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10","cj","cq","ck","s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8","s9","s10","sj","sq","sk","d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9","d10","dj","dq","dk"};

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {


        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++)
        {

            int index = (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_CARDS);

            String temp = types[i];
            types[i] = types[index];
            types[index] = temp; 

        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Assignment12");
        Assignment12 applet = new Assignment12();
        applet.init();

        frame.getContentPane().add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void init()
    {

        card1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[0] + ".gif");

        card2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[1] + ".gif");

        card3 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[2] + ".gif");

        card4 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[3] + ".gif");

        card5 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[4] + ".gif");

        card6 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[5] + ".gif");

        card7 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[6] + ".gif");

        card8 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[7] + ".gif");

        card9 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[8] + ".gif");

        card10 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/" + types[9] + ".gif");

        repaint();



    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawImage(card1, 10, 10, this);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a JFrame and a main method if you're trying to display an applet?

Comment: I would get rid of all applet code, would display my image as an ImageIcon in a JLabel, and would get my image as a resource using `ImageIO.read(InputStream is)`. Key would be making sure that I'm using the correct path to the image -- and to avoid assuming that I am until I can test and prove that I am.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get my Java Applet to show the card images?

Load it as if it were an applet (would be the first step).  A simple test shows that the way of loading an applet seen above, leaves the `getDocumentBase()` method returning **`null`**.

Comment: (the image files are stored on my desktop) what would I do to make it stop returning null, or what would I replace the getDocumentBase() with?

Comment: *"(the image files are stored on my desktop)"*  Well start ff with, they probably shouldn't be stored there.  They seem like an 'application resource' so Instead they should be in a directory relative to the source code, possibly so they can be included in the executable Jar. *"what would I do to make it stop returning null, or what would I replace the `getDocumentBase()` with?"*  That really depends on several factors, the first being, will this be deployed as an applet (`JApplet`), an application (`JFrame`), or both?

Comment: As far as my limited knowledge understands, this is a standalone JApplet. Does it being standalone make it both?